# How to check if a Socks5 proxy works

Tags: linux, proxy, socks5

Is there an easy way, preferably by using the Linux terminal, to check if a Socks5 proxy works?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you created the proxy by yourself you should first of all check whether there is an open port (the `p` argument only works if the concerning process is yours or you are root):

```
netstat -tlnp
```

This should give you a line like: (I have a proxy on `localhost:8888`)

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8888          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

If you found such a line or the proxy isn't yours, try sending packets through it. For example request a web page with `curl`:

```
curl --socks5 localhost:8888 binfalse.de
```

Should output some HTML stuff. Hope this helps to search for mistakes ;-)

---

**Aux**: For my example I created the proxy via:

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -D8888 someone@somewhere
```

Replace `someone` with your username and `somewhere` with your destination server. Of course using OpenSSH is just one method in a bunch of possible socks5 proxies.

Comment: ssh: Could not resolve hostname somewhere: Name or service not known

Comment: Of course you have to replace `someone@somewhere` with your username and your server, e.g. `ssh -D8888 YOURUSER@YOURHOST` ;-)

Comment: On windows, the netstat command is:  `nestat -an`   or `netstat -an | grep LISTEN` if you have grep in your path.

Comment: Thanks for the `curl` hint. FWIW, curl also supports `--socks5-hostname` which is like `--socks5` but does not attempt to locally resolve the hostname of the submitted URL (which may be super useful for connecting to intranets).

Answer (score 9):

To get curl to resolve the DNS on the other side, change `--socks5` with `--socks5-hostname`.

See [the man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize why my request was failing until using this.

Answer (score 9):

The following command will test whether Socks 5 proxy works at `localhost:8080`:

```
timeout 5 curl -x socks5://localhost:8080 http://example.com/
```

Otherwise it'll timeout after 5 seconds. If you don't have a `timeout` command, drop it.

Comment: `curl --max-time` and `curl --connect-timeout` can be used instead of `timeout`

Answer (score 4):

You may connect with netcat and follow the rules of [RFC 1928](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1928) to talk to the server. You'd have to be able to type and read non-printable characters though, or log them to a file for further examination.

E.g., to test if it's a SOCKS5 server and find out which of no-auth, gssapi, or usr+pwd authentication methods it would support, send 0x05 0x03 0x00 0x01 0x02.  A SOCKS5 server prepared to use usr+pwd authentication would reply 0x05 0x02.

Or here's how to check if it's a SOCKS5 server and no-auth (method 0) works:

```
echo 050100 | xxd -p -r | netcat -o out.txt {server} {port}
```

After you interrupt that, towards the end of out.txt it should have produced 0x05 0x00 if the server supports that method (0), or 0x05 0xFF if it does not.